How can I adjust the text Field to continue in a new line that has a different size from the original one?
I'm working on a report in JasperReports Studio (that has a format type of jrxml) and I need to display my text across multiple lines. The requirement is for the text to start on one line and, upon reaching the end, continue on the next line starting from the beginning of the second line, not just below where it ended.
Stretching the text field vertically (interline spacing) is not a suitable solution for me. Is it possible to configure text fields in JasperReports to meet these requirements? If so, how can I achieve this?here is the image
Here is the code in jrxml, the $F{razones} refers to the null value which in this case is not assigned yet:
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="684" y="640" width="626" height="30" uuid="30779b31-a316-41b4-ab24-652174ad900d"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="18"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{razones}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>

thanks
